# Restore .cs files from debug folder generated for a ASP.NET Core application

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, restore, bin-folder

I have been programming an ASP.NET Core application for the last couples of weeks. Just a "small project" to put on my resume so I can get my first job. But today when I tried to upload it to Github I somehow deleted all the .cs files which really suck big time! However, I still have the files from the bin/debug folder in the original folder where all the .cs files was. Is there any way to restore the .cs files? I have been trying to use .NET Reflector but without any luck because I don't know how it works.

I don't know what information is relevant to know, so please feel free to ask for more details!

Best Regards
Christian

Comment: If its only those .cs files (classes) then You can use DotPeek to extract from your .dll assemblies you still have. 
https://www.jetbrains.com/decompiler/
Open that assembly using dotpeek and extract the content of the class, create another project and paste and make it there.

Comment: [dotPeek is free](https://www.jetbrains.com/decompiler/) - open the compiled DLL and see what you get.

Comment: Why don't you do data recovery on your hard drive

Comment: Because of a small SSD hard drive I have turned off data recovery which is painful to admit right now...

Comment: Another thing to learn from this is to add code to source control as soon as you start on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[ILSpy](https://github.com/icsharpcode/ILSpy/releases) might be easier to use. Just load the binary and it will decompile each type. You can just copy-paste the code.

Comment: It was far more easy, thank you so much!!! I have all the .cs files now which is much better than nothing. But it would be nice if I could restore my .cshtml files and my .js file as well? Is that possible somehow? 
And thank you again!

Comment: Those files are not stored in any assembly, they usually sit one folder higher relative to bin/, so probably you lost them - file recovery software might help you here